# Add youtube video on site through link

Tags: php, hyperlink, youtube, embed

I'm working on a project and there is something I can't quite solve.

Users can add YouTube videos to their profiles by just adding the YouTube clip's link in a form, E.G:

Youtube link: `youtube.com/watch?v=9YgjZ4oPrj4`

Now once the user clicks submit the video has to be embedded. The only problem is that I only need this part `9YgjZ4oPrj4` for embedding 
(see code below)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9YgjZ4oPrj4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now, as you know, YouTube videos have different types of links:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=9YgjZ4oPrj4
youtu.be/9YgjZ4oPrj4
```

How do I make this one work?
It's actually the same as Facebook uses

Comment: Use regex for example, but you didn't try so wouldn't I ...

Comment: @Sam I see you don't use to accept answers, which is a pity, this leads to you having a bad karma and not receiving any answers. Please look at the two answers you were given below and accept one.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I did not know that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that will pull the YouTube ID from a string. **Note** I just [copied it from Forrst](http://forr.st/~T6O), but it should do what you want.

```
function youtube_id($url){
  $url = preg_replace('((http://)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)(/v/|/watch\?v=|/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(.*))',"$5",$url);
  return (preg_match('(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*){11,18})',$url) ? $url : '');
}
```

The following urls were tested.

```
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPgYbdQ1kQ&feature=feedu"
"www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPgYbdQ1kQ&feature=feedu"
"youtube.com/watch?v=pkPgYbdQ1kQ&feature=feedu"
"http://www.youtube.com/v/pkPgYbdQ1kQ&feature=feedu"
"www.youtube.com/v/pkPgYbdQ1kQ&feature=feedu"
"http://youtu.be/pkPgYbdQ1kQ"
"youtu.be/pkPgYbdQ1kQ"
```

Comment: @SamHendrickx do not just say "thank you", actually upvote and accept the answer. That's how things work on SO.

Comment: But I can't becuase my reputation is lower then 15

Answer (score 1):

You could build a map of hostnames and closures:

```
$tubes = array(
  'youtube.com' => function($parsed_url) {
    //$parsed_url contains data as returned by parse_url()
  },
  'youtu.be' => function($parsed_url) {
    //
  },
);
```

Then parse the content with a regex, get the URLs, and pass them through a call to the appropiate element in your map.

**This method is more versatile**, because you're not limited to youtube, you can add helpers for any host easily, including vimeo and god knows what, as needs pop up.

**Sample working implementation**, I'll leave the rest to you:

```
<?php
$text = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=9YgjZ4oPrj4

http://youtu.be/9YgjZ4oPrj4';

$tubes = array(
    'youtube.com' => function($parse_url) {
        parse_str($parse_url['query'], $query);
        return "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/$query[v]' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    },
);

$replace = function($matches) use ($tubes) {
    $url = parse_url($matches[0]);
    if(isset($tubes[$url['host']])) {
        return $tubes[$url['host']]($url);
    }
    return $matches[0];
};

$matches = preg_replace_callback('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/', $replace, $text);

var_dump($matches);
```

If you need new heuristics, then just add them to the `$tubes` map.